# In Cordova iPad app, the soft keyboard pushes the DIV position upward

Tags: html, ios, cordova, ipad, soft-keyboard

I am working on a cordova based iPad app. It has a bottom panel DIV (kind of footer) uses following CSS style to dock in the bottom of the screen.

```
{position:fixed;bottom: 0px}
```

When user focus on text box, the soft keyboard appears and push the bottom panel upward. When text box losses the focus, the soft keyboard disappears, but the bottom panel DIV remains in middle of the screen.

This is not happening when keyboard was close explicitly by clicking on the hide button(button in bottom right corner) in the keyboard. Also, there is no issue if bottom panel DIV uses `{position:absolute}`.

**Other Information:**

iOS Version    : 7.1.1

Cordova version: 4.2

I have already doing `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` in the onblur event of all textbox control to restore the window after keyboard is closed.

Also, I am using following viewport setting

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,target-densitydpi=medium-dpi;width=device-width;height=device-height" />
```

What is the best solution to fix this issue without using `{position:absolute}` style?

Comment: Why dont you want to use `position:absolute`?

Comment: ‘position:fixed;’ helps to dock the div at the bottom respective to the window. This helps to use the same code for android with multiple screen size.

Comment: But `position: absolut` leads to the same effect. I do not get the point why not to forego with that...